# Java uses synchronisation... What does Haskell use?

Tags: java, multithreading, haskell, corruption

So I am pretty new to Haskell and would like to know, if synchronisation is used to prevent corruption when multithreading Java, how is this done in Haskell? I've only found useless or overly complicated responses on google.

Comment: [Basically, STM](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/software-transactional-memory.html). `atomically` is somewhat similar to a synchronised block.

Comment: [There's a whole book on it](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/pcph/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous since one may use multithreading for either concurrency or parallelism, which are distinct problems with distinct solutions.

In both cases, you'll need to make sure your programs are compiled with SMP support and ran using multiple RTS threads: see the GHC manual's [section about concurrency](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-concurrent.html#using-concurrent).

### Concurrency

As others have pointed out, synchronization will be a non problem in the vast majority of your code, since you'll mostly be dealing with pure functions. This is true in any language if you <s>keep mutable state and libraries that rely on it under armed guard</s> religiously avoid mutable state unless it is properly wrapped behind a *pure API*. Concurrency is an area where Haskell shines because its semantics *require* purity. Types are used to *describe* impure operations instead, making it dead easy to spot code where some sort of synchronization might be needed.

Typically, your application's state will be backed by a transactional database which will handle synchronization and persistence for you. *You will not need any additional synchronization at all if your concurrent application does not have additional state.*

In other cases, haskell has a handy [Software Transactional Memory](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm) implementation. It allows you to write and compose code written in an imperative-looking style, without explicit locking, while having atomicity and guarantees against deadlocks. It is *the* foolproof(tm) way to write concurrent code.

Lastly, there are some low-level primitives available in `base`: plain old mutable references with [`IORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html), [semaphores](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-QSem.html), and [`MVars`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html) which can be used as if they were variables protected by a mutex.

> There also are channels in `base`, but beware: they are unbounded !

### Parallelism

This is also an area where Haskell shines because of its non-strict semantics. *Non-strictness* allows you to write code that expresses your logic in a straightforward manner while not getting committed to a specific evaluation order.

As a consequence, you can describe a [parallel evaluation strategy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.1.0/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html) separately from the business logic. Writing parallel code is then just a matter of placing the right annotation in the right spot.

Here is an example that was/is used in production at [Bdellium](https://medium.com/@folsen/haskell-in-production-bdellium-1df48de40e19):

```
map outputParticipant parts `using` parListChunk 10 rdeepseq
^^^^^ business logic ^^^^^^         ^^^^ eval. strategy ^^^^
```

The code can be understood as follows: Parallel workers will fully evaluate the results of mapping the `outputParticipant` function to individual items in the `parts` list, distributing the work in chunks of 10 elements.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will pertain to functional languages in general - no synchronisation are needed. As functions in functional programming have no side effects: functions accept a value and return a value, there's no mutable state. Such functions are inherently thread safe.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the response. Can probably tell that I haven't even touched a functional programming language before. So it doesn't affect data shared between the threads at all when running?

Comment: As far as I know, basic premise of functional programming is that the data is immutable, so threads can read it freely, because it won't change. I do not know of any exception to this rule, though I am not very experienced in FP myself.

Comment: While there is a point to this argument, it's still a bit rash to say _no synchronisation is needed_ in pure functional languages. True is, _many_ tasks that would require synchronisation in imperative languages to exploit multithreading can be done in Haskell by just tossing in a few `par` combinators. But a lot of these applications could also parallelised with simply a `#pragma omp parallel` or the like in imperative languages. Many multithreading applications use _concurrency_ rather than parallelism, and that's not completely trivial even in Haskell (though it _can_ be done quite nicely).